# I am trying to map IDs from inside a list of objects into a new list using React js

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a new list from an existing one by fetching the IDs from the existing list of objects and copy it into a new list which is accessible throughout the component.

This existing list is being returned as part of response of a BE API

```
const key = [];
await RequestPortInService.fetchCurrentServices().then(response => {

   response.currentServiceList.map(key => (
         key = response.currentServiceList.serviceId
   ));
   alert(key);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your key values in the object  response.currentServiceList.map will be on **key** so try using

```
   var newSerivceIds = {};

          await RequestPortInService.fetchCurrentServices().then(response => {
            newSerivceIds= response.currentServiceList.map(key => 
                    {return key.serviceId});
            })
            alert(newSerivceIds)
```

Comment: `  let newKey  = [];
        await RequestPortInService.fetchCurrentServices().then(response => {

            response.currentServiceList.map(key => (
                 newKey = key.serviceId
            ));
            console.log("SERVICE ID : "+newKey);
        });

with the above code i am only able to fetch a single key in console , whereas i want to fetch the  entire service ID list

Comment: getting a compilation issue here :(

`     let newKey  = {};
        await RequestPortInService.fetchCurrentServices().then(response => {
            
            newKey = response.currentServiceList.map(key => (
                return  key.serviceId
            ));
            console.log("SERVICE ID : "+newKey);

Comment: what that issue is about ?

Comment: Check now thats syntax issue

Comment: glad it helps , upvote if the answer helps happy coding !